# unable to conect google cloud compute server using putty

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying google cloud compute server, everything is working fine like I am able to connect using open in browser window , But when I am trying to connect using putty , its not working , i am following below docs,
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#putty

I also added public key into vm instance but no luck , when I am trying to connect using putty always getting below error:

Disconnected : no supported authentication method available (server sent :publickey,gssapi-keygen,gssapi-with-mic)

on server /var/log/secure
below error there,
 error: Received disconnect from 223.165.28.230: 14: No supported authenti
cation methods available [preauth]

don't knew why this is not connecting .any one have any clue, please reply.

Comment: Did you add your newly-generated public key to the GCE list of project-wide public SSH keys (stored as project metadata)? Are you SSHing with the correct username? Take a look at equivalent instructions here: https://gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b.

Comment: Yes I uploaded ssh key on project medadata sshkey ,obvious i am using right username when I am connecting through putty.

Comment: Hi Jarmod , Yes i Follow the step mentioned gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b, it is working fine for new instance , but not for already running instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am new in Google cloud server so it takes sometime  to undestand its authentication model,obvious borwser based ssh is good for new user but when we are handling large number of server better to go with key based (putty) method,because it is already used to and sometime we need to transfer file from our local workstation so that time key based auth is best.

finally I understnad the auth/key management of google cloud, yes below  google docs are good for understand .
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance
and for generating key ,
gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b

Above link  is very very good for creating new instance/single node key management, so please read this docs first.

Note : please use cluster wise key for better management of users and servers authentication process, add key details in metadata -- sshkey , add your key to get access on all vm, yes sometime we need node wise so follow gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b ,to enable only one user for this node disable project -wise key under vm edit ssh key options .

Please read both docs before creating google cloud VM server.
Thanks Jarmod for your reply and make me understand the process